# OleDbCommand Failed

Tags: c#, database, oledb

I use this code to add a Record to the database Clients.accdb 
but it failed when I try to execute the command (if I open the database with Microsoft Access the command works so it's not a wrong command).

My Add function is as follows:

```
public static void AddClient(string ipAddress, string macAddrress, string machineName) 
{
    string command = "INSERT INTO tbl_Clients (ipAddress, macAddress, machineName) VALUES ('" + ipAddress +"', '" + macAddrress + "', '" + machineName + "')";
    OleDbConnection connection= new OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringStatic());
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, connection);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // here it move to the catch..why ??
        while (dr.Read())  
        {
        }                         
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)   
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)         
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I used nearly the same (only the connection string and the database were different) and there it worked.

Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: What you mean by not work. If getting any exception, please post here ?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: i get no error; it move to the catch and don't execute the command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your query with [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx). `ExecuteReader` returns data which is not meaningful with `INSERT` statement.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` methods manually.

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringStatic()))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
      cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tbl_Clients (ipAddress, macAddress, machineName)
                          VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ip", ipAddress);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@mac", macAddrress);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", machineName);
      connection.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} // <-- Both connection and command are disposed here
```

Comment: @csharp.tester If you connection with _database_, then yes. This type of nested statements dispose your `connection` and `cmd` objects on `}` line.

Comment: thanks it works ! you say i have to use the ExecuteNonQuery because of the insert, so if i want to use select i have to use ExecuteQuery ? and how can i read the data ?

Comment: i got from the select ?

Comment: @csharp.tester If you use `SELECT` statement, that means you want to get some data from your query, executing it is not enough. You can use `ExecuteReader`, `ExecuteScalar` or you can use `OracleDataAdapter`. Read their documentations and use it which one is perfect for you.